# Pip: install --find-links on multiple folder

Tags: pip, virtualenv, python-venv

I create a virtual environment with the command:

> python -m venv ./my_venv

After activating this virtual env, I want to install some packages with .tar.gz archives.

My method to install my packages is explained in the following part:

```
PACKAGE1='/path/to/the/folder1'
PACKAGE2='/path/to/the/folder2'
PACKAGE3='/path/to/the/folder3'
PACKAGE4='/path/to/the/folder4'

pip install --find-links="${PACKAGE1}" package_1==1.0.0
pip install --find-links="${PACKAGE2}" package_2==1.0.0
pip install --find-links="${PACKAGE3}" package_3==1.0.0
pip install --find-links="${PACKAGE4}" package_4==1.0.0
```

Now I want to use a file *requirements.txt* like:

```
package_1==1.0.0
package_2==1.0.0
package_3==1.0.0
package_4==1.0.0
```

and run the command:

> pip install --find-links="${PACKAGE}" -r requirements.txt

**but**

I don't find the way to tell pip to install using multiple folder.
Here is an example of what I want:

```
PACKAGE1='/path/to/the/folder1'
PACKAGE2='/path/to/the/folder2'
PACKAGE3='/path/to/the/folder3'
PACKAGE4='/path/to/the/folder4'

pip install --find-links="${PACKAGE1}" --find-links="${PACKAGE2}" --find-links="${PACKAGE3}" --find-links="${PACKAGE4}" -r requirements.txt
```

Obviously, I didn't work.

Can you help me ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `--find-links` [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-f) again:

> If a local path ... that’s a directory, then look for archives in the directory listing.

So `/path/to/the/folder4` for example will need to contain an archive/wheel for `package4`. This will not work if `/path/to/the/folder4` is just the source directory/root for `package4`.